# VBA - Insert rows below a dynamic header

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to insert a new row below a frozen header row at the top of a spreadsheet. The issue I face is the amount of rows in the header is ever changing but I always want the row to be inserted at the first line below the header. Is there a flag in the row that says its frozen? which I could just count the amount of rows with said flag, add 1 and insert row. Any help would be very helpful.

Matt

Comment: When you say _frozen_, do you mean you used `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes` (in VBA), or `View | Freeze Panes | Freeze Panes` (from the ribbon). Or do you mean `Split` where you have multiple scrollable views of the same spreadsheet in the same window?

Comment: I mean View | Freeze Panes | Freeze top row, From the ribbon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are!

```
Sub InsertRowBelowHeader()
    Rows(ActiveWindow.SplitRow + 1).Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Close, but possibly no cigar. The OP asked about _.FreezePane_ which is different and can be set independently of _Split_. If he's really talking about _SplitPanes_ you nailed it, if not, I don't think it can be done.

Comment: That just inserts a row at the top of the page inside the header and shifts everything in the header down. I need to add a row outside of the header

Comment: All I did was go to View > Freeze pane > Freeze top row in excel and then inserted rows on top of that header. I just want to use VBA to along with other things insert a row right below the "header" frozen row. The thing is the amount of rows in the header is always changing but I want the row always inserted right after the header.

Comment: I reproduced all actions you described, then launched the code, and I've got a row inserted below the frozen rows. I'm on Excel 2007 Win7 x64.

Comment: Okay, This worked, I must of had an old piece of code still in there that was inserting a row at the top. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `FreezePanes` then I think you go this route:

```
Sub InsertRowBelowHeader()
    Rows(ActiveWindow.Panes(1).VisibleRange.Rows.Count + 1).Insert
End Sub
```

**Before**, the freeze line is below row 5.  Freeze pane was done on cell `A6`

[image: before]

**After**, a row is added to split a/b

[image: after]

Here is a relevant discussion which came up on Google for freeze panes and VBA.  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/275645-identifying-freeze-panes-position-sheet-using-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: Excellent!  `ActiveWindow.Panes(1).VisibleRange.Rows.Count + 1` will give you the row number _below_ the `freeze line`.

Comment: My terminology might be incorrect, all this does is inserts a line in the header and increases the amount of rows the header contains by 1

Comment: When I run that code on my end, it adds the row below the freeze line.  Maybe add a picture to your post so we can see what we're dealing with?

Comment: Your answer solved the question OP asked. His acceptance of the other answer indicates that wasn't the question he meant to ask...

Comment: At least I learned how to access `VisibleRange`... that's new.