# Excel: How to retrieve the frozen range of the Worksheet programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, excel, range, vsto, freeze

I'm using VSTO to build an Excel add-in.

I want to build two functions. The first one, stores the frozen range at my Excel.Range variable called RNG and then unfreeze panes, using the following command.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
```

The second function selects the range and freezes it again. With the following

```
RNG.Select()
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

What i don't know is how to store the frozen range before unfreeze the window.

Does someone can help me with doing this, or knows some other workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242193/vba-insert-rows-below-a-dynamic-header/30242582#30242582).  It gives the code for retrieving the `VisibleRange`.

Comment: If you can post your completed code as an answer below (and mark it answered), that help others who stumble upon this.  It also helps those of us looking for unanswered questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Byron 's help, I solved my problem. Here is my code!

```
'Flag that indicates if there is a "frozen" scenario stored in the other variables
Private frozen_scenario As Boolean
'Range that marks the first cell of the frozen header
Private range_freeze_begin As Excel.Range
'Range that marks the the first cell not contained by the frozen header
Private range_freeze_end As Excel.Range
'Range that marks the the first visible cell (in the not fixed pane)
Private first_visible_cell_not_fixed As Excel.Range

'Unfreezes the panes, saving the current scenario
Private Sub unfreezeLines()
    With Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow
        If .FreezePanes Then
            Dim frozen_pane_limit_line As Integer
            Dim frozen_pane_limit_column As Integer

            frozen_pane_limit_line = .Panes(1).VisibleRange.Rows.Count + 1
            frozen_pane_limit_column = .Panes(1).VisibleRange.Columns.Count + 1

            If .Panes.Count = 2 Then
                If .Panes(1).VisibleRange(1, 1).Row = .Panes(2).VisibleRange(1, 1).Row Then
                    frozen_pane_limit_line = 1
                Else
                    frozen_pane_limit_column = 1
                End If

                Me.first_visible_cell_not_fixed = .Panes(2).VisibleRange(1, 1)
            Else '4 panes
                Me.first_visible_cell_not_fixed = .Panes(4).VisibleRange(1, 1)
            End If

            Me.range_freeze_begin = .Panes(1).VisibleRange(1, 1)
            Me.range_freeze_end = Me.sheet.Cells(frozen_pane_limit_line, frozen_pane_limit_column)
            Me.frozen_scenario = True

            .FreezePanes = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'Recovers the frozen state, exactly like it was when the first function was called
Private Sub recuperaLinhasCongeladas()
    If Me.frozen_scenario Then
        'Creating the frozen header again
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Goto(Me.range_freeze_begin, True)
        Me.range_freeze_end.Select()
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        'Showing the same cell at the top
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Goto(Me.first_visible_cell_not_fixed, True)

        Me.frozen_scenario = False
    End If
End Sub
```